# Form submit after GTM dataLayer push

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM's Enhanced Ecommerce to report events via pushes to the `dataLayer` variable.

I have a situation where I need to push an event and immediately submit a form in the event callback. Google in theory provides the `eventCallback` mechanism for this, but consider the following code:

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',
    'impressions': [
     {
       'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
       'id': '67890',
       'price': '33.75',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Black',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 2
     }]
  }
},{
    'eventCallback': function() {
        document.location = productObj.url; // works
        document.getElementById('form-id').submit(); // fails (!?!)
    }
});
</script>
```

Notes:

1. There no Javascript errors on the page
2. The form `#form-id` exists (not a matter of typos)

Bottom line: how do I go about causing the form to submit after the push? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Maybe 'eventCallback' doesn't work cause you push only raw ecommerce data without any 'event' ?

Comment: And double check brackets. (i think there's at least one } to much)

Comment: Right, the JSON is definitely invalid in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason as for why you are using GTM to submit a form (particularly after a product impression)? This is probably beyond its intended use and sounds way too hacky.

Assuming the website does the push itself, you could submit the form immediately after the dataLayer.push on the webpage script, and using GTM's own [form submit delay](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en) catch the push, assemble the product impression tag yourself, then let the form submit as expected after it fired. That should do it.